# Sibling selector in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to apply css to siblings elements

Example

```
<div>
    <div class="e"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
</div>
```

I want them E and F to be red color, but only if they are siblings.

In case like

```
<div>
    <div class="e"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="f"></div>
</div>
```

they are not siblings, so they will have different colors.

No js.

Comment: Are these the only two possible scenarios? If so then ced-b's answer is enough. Otherwise there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sibling selector:

```
.e ~ div {
    background-color:red;
}
```

This targets all the `<div>` siblings of .e

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/GnzXg/3/)

Comment: Use diffent background color will make better vision effect. Anyway, it is an useful answer.

Comment: I think `.e ~ .f, .f ~ .e` would make more sense in case a strict sibling condition is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this one is a bit crazy, but works as long as you only have two:

```
.f:nth-child(2), .e:nth-last-child(2) {
   background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wvLaB/

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/creativevilla/ae2nf/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="e">e</div>
    <div class="f">f</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="e">e</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="f">f</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div > div {
 background-color: cyan;   
}

div > div:only-child {  
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Curious why you used `>` in one selector and space for another.

Answer (score 0):

not possible.

For some information what is possible, check http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/.

unfortunately, the `~`-operator has a "direction". `.e ~ .f` would match, but not `.f ~ .e`.

`.e ~ .f` means: an ".f", that has an ".e" *immediately* before, not as a sibling in the common sense!

`.e ~ .f` selects only class "f", similar to how `.ul > .li`selects only `.li`'s but not the `.ul`'s. And you can't reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage defining class like this:

html

```
<div class="sib">
    <div class="e"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
</div>

<div class="si">
    <div class="e"></div>
</div>
<div class="si">
    <div class="f"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.sib > e, .sib > f{
     /*code in here */
}
```

In case your html its easier like this `.sib > div{/*code in here */}`

And for the second html you can do as this

```
div.si ~ .e, div.si ~ .f
```